# No products are showing after re-index - Magento upgrade - 2.1 to 2.2 then 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, catalog, category-products, magento-upgrade

I followed these steps in order to upgrade Magento (current version: 2.1.9):

1. Upgraded to 2.2.8
2. Upgraded to 2.3.3

The one issue that I am stuck is that after upgrading to 2.2 or 2.3 and on reindexing there is too less entry in store wise tables.

Also there is too less entry in search table as well.

```
catalog_category_product_index_store1
catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1
```

I have total 2,20,000 products.

Any idea ?

**Update:**
When adding a new product (simple) from admin I am able to get it in above tables and also in fronted.

Any help ??

Comment: is elastic search enabled?

Comment: hmm, in backend catalog search is set to Mysql.

Comment: my concern is that only few entry are there after reindex... say 120 only.

Comment: please full reindex once. clear cache.

Comment: ran same but no luck...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure products are added to the website.

```
Catalog > Products | Select All
```

Then on the Options dropdown, "Update Attributes" > Select the "Websites" tab on the left. Check the boxes under "Add Product to Websites" > Save

Then Reindex and Clear Cache

```
bin/magento c:f

bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

If the issue still persists please check the "inventory_stock_1" view is there in the database or not if not please create the view bu running the below SQL.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `inventory_stock_1`;

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`<DB_USER>`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY INVOKER VIEW `inventory_stock_1`  AS  select distinct `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,`legacy_stock_status`.`website_id` AS `website_id`,`legacy_stock_status`.`stock_id` AS `stock_id`,`legacy_stock_status`.`qty` AS `quantity`,`legacy_stock_status`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable`,`product`.`sku` AS `sku` from (`cataloginventory_stock_status` `legacy_stock_status` join `catalog_product_entity` `product` on(`legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` = `product`.`entity_id`)) ;
```

Comment: i cheked and products are added in store view

Comment: @NarendraVyas please check the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

By upgrading magento version there will not be any issues for your products or any data contains in db if it's not face any db crash. Please check the below tips.

1. Always make sure your system requirements are completely supporting for upgraded version[eg: for magento2.1 -> will works with less than php7, but for magento2.2 and 2.3 need at least of php7.1.3].
2. Make sure all your modules are up to date and will support for your latest magento versions.
3. While doing re-indexing make sure all the components are re-indexed properly without failed.
4. If failed or faced any issue for re-index check, reset the indexed component and re-index it again.
5. Once re-indexed successfully clear the cache by running clean and flush command.
6. provide proper permission for the folders.
7. Still having issues check the logs with magento and web server.

Hope this could help.

Comment: I have disabled all custom modules.
The issue is that i am not getting all entry in index table store wise

Comment: Check your inventory_stock, In stock etc..in db and also please cross check whether your all the data are migrated successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Once try to delete all stores ( flat) tables and then run again reindex. It will create them again automatically.

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex
bin/magento c:c
bin/magento c:f
```

**Don't delete all maganto tables, only delete store flat tables.**

Comment: you mean deleting  catalog_category_flat_store_1 ??

Comment: Yes, also removed product flat tables.

Comment: okay let me delete for 1 store to test. But i have disabled flat already in admin ??

Comment: not working still

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that all products are added and enable on your website. Beside that, please check whether the view **inventory_stock_1** is in the database

Comment: From where I can check this inventory_stock_1 in database ??

Comment: I just checked and the view inventory_stock_1 exists in database. Also it has entry of all pre existing products as well.
Any idea what is creating problem for me ???

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below command to re-index product

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex
bin/magento c:c
bin/magento c:f
```

if still issues occur then check whether the product are assigned to its root category `i.e "Default Category".`